# In Vite, how do I specify a subdirectory of my server for the assets?

Tags: vite, rollup

I'm building a React app with Vite that is hosted in a subdirectory (`/pwa`) on my webserver.

The main site is a Drupal 10 site.

Previously, I was using Create React App to build my PWA.  I have now converted the PWA to use Vite instead, but the problem is that when I run `npm run build` and copy the `dist` directory to `/pwa` on my server, looking for the assets fails because the build targets `www.example.com/assets` instead of `www.example.com/pwa/assets`.

How can I modify the vite config to tell it that I need the final output to look for assets in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 10):

In Vite, this is called the [base](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) option.

In **vite.config.ts**:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/pwa',
```

Comment: This answer seems unsatisfactory. The build should not have to know where it's hosted in order to work. Is there a way to get everything to simply link to a relative path?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) option.

If you're not sure where the app will deployed to, you may use a relative base like the following:

```
export default defineConfig({
  base:'./',
});
```